# Android Encryption

Tags: encryption

If I encrypt my phone i know it will protect my data, however if for example my phone is stolen or lost, the person with it, would they be able to just hard reset it and use it or resale it, or encryption renders it unusable unless you get the pass code?

Comment: What you describe is nothing encryption can protect against. Encryption protects your data; although FRP (factory reset protection) requires to enter the login information of the last owner (you) before you can use the device again. However there are many ways to bypass this so even this won't protect your phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your encrypted phone gets stolen, person with it can factory reset and erase all your data **permanently**.

But if he tries to resale it, he has to overcome factory reset protection, which will ask for previous owners info. Unfortunately, by many ways this can be bypassed unless you are on latest security patches and updates.